# Forces and momentum in a hemispherical pipe.

Tags: forces, momentum

Consider the hemispherical pipe, where the measured force is the force upwards.

F (force on pipe = measured force) = mass flow rate times (u1 + u2)

[image]

[image]

My answer:

Part 1: If u2 is less than u1, that means there is a greater change in velocity and therefore momentum.

Part 2: Since u2 is less, that means according to the equation, the measured force will be smaller.

However my problem with this answer is that, friction is acting upwards against the fluid and will therefore have an upwards component. Does this not mean that the measured force should increase?

Two contradicting theories, anyone know which answer is correct?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your answer to Part 1 is incorrect. There is a *smaller* change in velocity $(u_2+u_1)$ and momentum. However, your conclusion in Part 2 is correct : there is a smaller upward force on the hemisphere.

The water exerts outward and downward frictional forces on the hemisphere. The outward forces all have equal and opposite pairs, so they cancel out, but the downward forces add together. The net friction force on the hemisphere is downward.

So both arguments agree that friction decreases the upward force on the hemisphere.